# Spring log and store at application level all information from any http requests

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

In  my Spring application for a security purpose I need to log and store(for example in RDBMS or NoSQL database) at application level all information from any http requests to my API. I need to log user IP address, agent etc etc.

Is there any standard way in Spring Framework to implement this functionality or do I need to create custom filters and implement everything it by myself?

Comment: All web servers provide access logs natively. See https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Logging for tomcat, for example.

Comment: Thanks but I'm going to store this information at application level

Comment: So, you don't want to log anymore. You want to store. You still didn't specify where. It's hard to provide any answer if your requirements are that vague. But anyway, you'll probably need to implement it by yourself.